# Convergence of conditional expectations $E[X|Y_i]$.

Tags: conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables and suppose that the sequence $Y_i$ converges $L^1$ to $Y$:
$$Y_i\overset{L_1}{\longrightarrow}Y$$
Does $E[X|Y_i]$ also converge $L^1$ to $E[X|Y]$?:
$$E[X\mid Y_i]\overset{L_1}{\longrightarrow} E[X\mid Y]$$

Comment: Does the joint distributions $(X,Y_i)$ converge to $(X,Y)$ in some sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer the specific question here**: no.

For example, with $X\in L^1$, define $Y_i=i^{-1}X$.

Then $Y_i\to 0$ in $L^1$, but $$E[X|Y_i]=E[X|i^{-1}X]=X\not\to E[X|0]=E[X]$$ except in the case when all the mass of $X$ is at a single point.

**More generally**: The fact that $Y_i$ converge to $Y$ in $L^1$ does not tell you anything useful about whether $E[X|Y_i]\to E[X|Y]$. The random variables $Y_i$, $Y$ only impact on the truth of the latter statement through their associated $\sigma$-algebras. That's why Lévy's Upward Theorem, the most relevant theorem to answering this question, is formulated in terms of a filtration of $\sigma$-algebras.

**Lévy's Upward Theorem**. Suppose $X\in L^1$ and $(\mathcal{F}_i)_{i\geq 1}$ is a filtration (increasing sequence) of $\sigma$-algebras. Then $M_i:=E[X|\mathcal{F}_i]$ is a uniformly integrable martingale and $M_i\to E[X|\mathcal{F}_\infty]$ almost surely and in $L^1$, where $\mathcal{F}_\infty=\sigma(\cup_{i\geq 1}\mathcal{F}_i)$.

So, if $\sigma(Y_i)\uparrow\sigma(Y)$ then, by this theorem, we can conclude that $E[X|Y_i]\to E[X|Y]$ in $L^1$.

Comment: What if the $Y_i$ were $\sigma(Y)$-measurable?

Comment: I think that, if $\sigma(Y_i)\uparrow\sigma(Y)$, then you can use Lévy's Upward Theorem to conclude 'yes'.